# Two buttons open each his own overlay content

Tags: button, overlay, show, fadein

I want two buttons to trigger each his own overlay content (centered vertical and horizontal), but keep the overlay layout the same only the content is different. I wrote a good functional single overlay script for one button, but the two buttons aren't working. In the fiddle there is only the script for one button that i'm using, it is properly quite simple.

Here is the fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/foroloca/xaqskbxb/2/)

```
function funcShow(event){
event.preventDefault();
$('.overlay-info').fadeIn(400);}

function funcClose(event){
event.preventDefault();
$('.overlay-info').fadeOut(400);}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put click handlers on your divs using jquery in a document ready function as seen below. Its not as "nice" and accepted to put them in an onclick property like you have.

And also its always nice to have Ids for everything that you are going to use to do things with like click or close. So if you see the example below, you have the document ready function that puts a clickhandler on the first div (id="overlay-one") and the second div as well as the close functions. Try it! It worked for me in you fiddle.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#overlay-one").click(function(event){
        funcShow(event);
    });

    $("#overlay-two").click(function(event){
        funcShow2(event);
    });

    $("#close-one").click(function(event){
        funcClose(event);
    });

    $("#close-two").click(function(event){
        funcClose2(event);
    });
});
```

The document ready function executes after your page is loaded so the clikc handlers are added after the elements have been created. You can also use `.click` on for classes to add events to a lot of things at once such as `$("CLASS").click(function(){//stuff})`

Comment: Sorry not working for me, but can i ask you why did you put the click function on the overlay itself and not on the two different buttons. The overlay-one or -two must fadeIn or Out on button click and not click the overlay itself or i'm i missing something?

Comment: That was my bad, those Ids should go on the buttons and maybe it should be #overlay-one-button and #overlay-two-button. Make sure to take out the onClick as well so that it doesn't clash with the jquery click handler.

If you haven't tried that yet, that might be the problem. It all definitely worked when I put it in fiddle. Ids are always better than classes, especially when you want to grab one specific thing. If you can, always have Ids. Especially on important elements.